# How can I use ajax with google map api?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

when I'm trying to get json from google map Place API using ajax, I get [this](http://pastebin.com/CG2KBunk) error. I tried to use `jsonp` and `beforeSend` and they didn't work at all. This is my ajax code below.

```
var baseAPIUrl = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?';
$.ajax({
            url: baseAPIUrl += "origin=place_id:" + placeId[0] + "&destination=place_id:" + placeId[1] + apikey,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            crossDomain: true,
            success: function(data) {
                       do something..
            }
}
```

I'm trying to get direction from the url as json and do something with the direction information. Is there any ideas to do this? Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have a typo:

```
url: baseAPIUrl + "origin=place_id:" + placeId[0] + "&destination=place_id:" + placeId[1] + apikey,
```

It shouldn't be `baseAPIUrl +=` but `baseAPIUrl +`.

Second of all, you can't access URLs that are outside of your domain (localhost in this case).

Read about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

In short, you'd need to make an ajax request to your server and your server would make a request to google api.

Comment: Thanks I did it what you said

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mapProcess.php',                        
        type: 'POST',                                  
        data: {
            var1  :val1   // parameter
        },
        success: function(response){    // response from mapProcess.php
            // do your stuff here
        }
    });
});
```

Php:

```
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$address."&components=country:IN&key=your_key";

// CURL call to get data from API
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$APIresponse = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$resp = json_decode($APIresponse, true);
```

Comment: Why should I use php?

Comment: Because you can't access URLs that are outside of your domain. You have to make an ajax call to server and that will make a CURL call to google API.